# PHP, MySQL, AJAX - Bootstrap CSS style does not show up after calling AJAX result

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This is my first time posting here.

I'd like to show what the actually looks like because I'm having a hard time in explaining it in words.

Here is the link: http://handpickedph.comlu.com/index.php

This a system that assigns subjects with a room and time schedule.

First I need to select a room name from the selection menu, where the room names are being shown from the database.

As you can see there, I'm using a bootstrap and javascript for the buttons.

Once you select a room from the selection menu,
the table of schedule automatically updates.

The good news is it returns the value which it called from the database.
My problem is, when the table below updates, it doesn't show the button styles with it.

I think this problem has something to do with the javascript or with the positioning of the css links? Or is there something I need to add to my code?

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Here is the code for the index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>



    <!--=========Start of Toggle JS===============-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



      <style>
          body{ margin: 100px;}

      </style>

      <!--This is the script for updating the table of schedules-->
      <script type="text/javascript">     
        function getRoomschedTable(str)
        {   
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
                // Create the object for browsers
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {
                // Create the object for browser versions prior to IE 7
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                // if server is ready with the response
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) 
                {
                    // if everything is Ok on browser
                    if(xmlhttp.status==200) 
                    {    
                        //Update the div with the response
                        document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
            }
            //send the selected option id to the php page 
            xmlhttp.open("GET","tableresult2.php?q="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
      </script>
  </head>

<body>

            <?php
                //connect to database
                require_once "includes/db_connect_roomscheds.php";
                //call the tables
                $result = $con2->query("show tables");
            ?>


            <?php
            require_once "includes/db_connect_roomscheds.php";

            $query = "SELECT * FROM sy2015";
            $stmt = $con2->prepare( $query );
            $stmt->execute();

            //this is how to get number of rows returned
            $num = $stmt->rowCount();
            ?>

  <form action="ajazresult.php" method="post">
    <select name="roomsched" onchange="getRoomschedTable(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select Room:</option>
            <?php

                //check if more than 0 record found
                if($num>0){

                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            //extract row
                            //this will make $row['firstname'] to
                            //just $firstname only
                            extract($row);

                            //creating new table row per record
                echo "<option>{$roomid}</option>";

                        }
                }else{
                    echo "No record";
                }

            ?>
    </select>
  </form>
    <br>
    <h4>The schedule of the selected room:</h4>  

    <div id="details" class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Time</th>
                          <th>Sunday</th>
                          <th>Monday</th>
                          <th>Tuesday</th>
                          <th>Wednesday</th>
                          <th>Thursday</th>
                          <th>Friday</th>
                          <th>Saturday</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>7:00 AM - 7:30 AM</td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($sunday7)){echo $sunday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7sunday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($monday7)){echo $monday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7monday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($tuesday7)){echo $tuesday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7tuesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($wednesday7)){echo $wednesday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7wednesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($thursday7)){echo $thursday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7thursday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($friday7)){echo $friday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7friday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($saturday7)){echo $saturday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7saturday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>7:30 AM - 8:00 AM</td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($sunday73)){echo $sunday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73sunday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($monday73)){echo $monday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73monday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($tuesday73)){echo $tuesday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73tuesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($wednesday73)){echo $wednesday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73wednesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($thursday73)){echo $thursday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73thursday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($friday73)){echo $friday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73friday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($saturday73)){echo $saturday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73saturday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

    <!--============Start of Toggle JS==================-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-55669452-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the resulttable2.php

```
<!--=========Start of Toggle JS===============-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];
//Connect to database
require "includes/db_connect_roomscheds.php";


//Fetch the data from tables
            try {
                    //table selected from dropdown

                    //prepare query
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM sy2015 WHERE roomid = '$q'";
                    $stmt = $con2->prepare( $query );

                    //this is the first question mark
                    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['id']);

                    //execute our query
                    $stmt->execute();

                    //store retrieved row to a variable
                    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                    //values to fill up our form
                    $sunday7 = $row['7sunday'];
                    $monday7 = $row['7monday'];
                    $tuesday7 = $row['7tuesday'];
                    $wednesday7 = $row['7wednesday'];
                    $thursday7 = $row['7thursday'];
                    $friday7 = $row['7friday'];
                    $saturday7 = $row['7saturday'];
                    $sunday73 = $row['73sunday'];
                    $monday73 = $row['73monday'];
                    $tuesday73 = $row['73tuesday'];
                    $wednesday73 = $row['73wednesday'];
                    $thursday73 = $row['73thursday'];
                    $friday73 = $row['73friday'];
                    $saturday73 = $row['73saturday'];

                }catch(PDOException $exception){ //to handle error
                    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
                }



            ?>

    <div id="details" class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Time</th>
                          <th>Sunday</th>
                          <th>Monday</th>
                          <th>Tuesday</th>
                          <th>Wednesday</th>
                          <th>Thursday</th>
                          <th>Friday</th>
                          <th>Saturday</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>7:00 AM - 7:30 AM</td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($sunday7)){echo $sunday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7sunday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($monday7)){echo $monday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7monday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($tuesday7)){echo $tuesday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7tuesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($wednesday7)){echo $wednesday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7wednesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($thursday7)){echo $thursday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7thursday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($friday7)){echo $friday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7friday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($saturday7)){echo $saturday7;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='7saturday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>7:30 AM - 8:00 AM</td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($sunday73)){echo $sunday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73sunday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($monday73)){echo $monday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73monday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($tuesday73)){echo $tuesday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73tuesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($wednesday73)){echo $wednesday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73wednesday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($thursday73)){echo $thursday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73thursday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($friday73)){echo $friday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73friday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                          <td><?php if(isset($saturday73)){echo $saturday73;}else{echo "<input type='checkbox'  data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-on='Reserved' data-off='Available' name='73saturday' value='1'>"; } ?></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

    <!--============Start of Toggle JS==================-->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-55669452-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Htennek
i have debugged the code and found that you have passed two same ID to div after select from dropdown list'

```
<div id="details">
<div id="details" class="table-responsive">'
```

. please check you know why your style goes away.

Comment: Hi Annshuk! I appreciate your help. On what file can I see it? I can't seem to find these two consecutive same ID.

This is what I can only see.
<div id="details" class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-striped">

Comment: HI, Htennek
You can see this ID on DOM structure. please check this on firebug. and debug your code in firebug. may be it will help you to find duplicate IDs

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript doesnt fire-up when you change subject on the dropdown box

I suggest that you add a code to manually to change the styles of your checkboxes below this line

```
//Update the div with the response
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Kindly check the documentation of the 'bootstrap-toggle' plugin for that

Regards,
sora021

Comment: Hi sora! So I need to put another script below that line that will enable my css? Is that correct? Probably something like this? http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: Hello Htennek,

So I need to put another script below that line that will enable my css?
-Yes, it's not to enable the css but to fire the plugin you are using (bootstrap toggle plugin)

Probably something like this? javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml 
-I am not sure but upon examining it might work and would take more work than with what you have

Here's what I have in mind, add a class named 'toggles' on each of the checkbox on 2nd php file 

and add this below the mentioned script above 
`$('.toggles').bootstrapToggle();`

Comment: So I just have to copy and paste that same exact code below the mentioned script, and put 'toggles' class on each checkbox?